# PHP Server Configuration for File Uploads

Tags: php, upload

I did a multifile upload feature in one of my projects.
For this I use the flash version of [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

It works fine on my local dev machine and on one other server I have for testing, but it doesn't work on the production machine (of course).

After troubleshooting the problem I did find out, that the script to handle the uploading process doesn't receive all parameters in $_FILES on the problematic server.

`var_dump($_FILES)` on the working machines:

```
["Filedata"]=>
   array(5) {
     ["name"]=>
     string(10) "simple.pdf"
     ["type"]=>
     string(24) "application/octet-stream"
     ["tmp_name"]=>
     string(14) "/tmp/phpTnNROo"
     ["error"]=>
     int(0)
     ["size"]=>
     int(60911)
   }
 }
```

`var_dump($_FILES)` on the failing machine:

```
["Filedata"]=>
   array(1) {
     ["name"]=>
     string(10) "simple.pdf"
   }
 }
```

I don't know why, but there is not even an error number.

How could I fix that?

I use these PHP versions:

```
Dev Machine: PHP 5.3.15
Working Remote Machine: PHP 5.3.3
Failing Remote Machine: PHP 5.3.8
```

php.ini Configuration (Changed it to eliminate some configuration limit as the error source):

```
file_uploads = On
max_file_uploads = 200
upload_max_filesize = 1G
post_max_size = 1G
memory_limit = 256M
max_execution_time = 14000
max_input_time = 14000
```

Comment: is target folder in remote machine has read and write permission??

Comment: Yes, but I can't even do a `move_uploaded_file()`, because `$_FILES` doesn't contain the `tmp_name`

Comment: does form has a appropriate enctype attribute set?

Comment: @Sabin +1 for being thorough but if it's working locally but not live then unless his files are out of sync he must have the right enctype set atleast locally

Comment: like I said, I use uploadify and it works on other servers, but for the sake of troubleshoot I did test that in a short dummy script as well.

Comment: almost looks like it's getting truncated mid-upload... this is wierd, never seen that particular behaviour before. would be interested to find out why.

Comment: For test script, if you have set proper enctype for form and still not being able to upload file, then its likely the temporary folder where file is saved seems not accessible. Thats why you are not getting `tmp_name`  Can you check that?

Comment: For the problematic server, I had `upload_tmp_dir = /tmp` but ended up creating a folder in my document root with chmod 777 and setting `upload_tmp_dir` to this

Comment: I just wrote a file (via `file_put_contents`) to the folder, which is set as my `upload_tmp_dir`, successfully, so I think it's not a permissions thing, PHP can definitely access that folder.

Comment: Are there any news on this issue? I have the very same problem with PHP 5.3.8. No error code and rights to write the tmp dir are definitely given. Max file size is not exceeded, I even made sure there is no `LimitRequestBody` set anywhere. May this be a bug in PHP 5.3.8 on SLES ?

Comment: @pdinklag Yes, this is a somewhat widespread bug with PHP 5.3.8 on SLES (see https://www.google.at/#q=file+upload+bug+php+5.3.8+sles). We ended up upgrading PHP on the machine and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Check your HTML code for form, Did you change method of your form in production server? it seems on production server the browser does not upload file at all
for exmple the form code must be like:

```
<form method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file[]"><br />
  <input type="file" name="file[]"><br />
</form>
```

Comment: no, I checked out the same source from my git repository, but here is the dummy test script I wrote to track down the error: [code + output](https://gist.github.com/3487477)